# Ruby on Rails: Seed Data Not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration, data-migration

I'm trying to seed data for Users, Works, and Comments but when I query the database the only available data are the Users. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in formatting my code for Works and Comments? I'm doing a has many, through relationship where Comments is my joins table.

````
{ title:"Guernica", artist: "Pablo Picasso", year: "1937", medium: "oil"},
{ title: "The Birth of Venus", artist: "Sandro Botticelli", year: "1485", medium: "tempera"},
{ title: "The Kiss", artist: "Gustav Klimt", year: "1907", medium:"oil"},
{ title: "American Gothic", artist: "Grant Wood", year: "1930" , medium: "oil"},
{ title: "Nighthawks", artist: "Edward Hopper", year: "1942", medium: "oil"},
{ title: "The Nightwatch", artist: "Rembrandt", year: "1642" , medium: "oil"},
{ title: "Campbell's Soup Cans", artist: "Andy Warhol" , year: "1961" , medium: "syntheic polymer paint"},
{ title: "The Great Wave off Kanagawa", artist: "Hokusai", year: "1820" , medium: "print"},
{ title: "David", artist:"Michelangelo", year: "1501" , medium: "marble"}])


Comment.create({headline:"Comment 1", description: "I think this piece is in France"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 2", description: "This is actually a huge work of art in person"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 3", description: "Why is this artist known for this piece?"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 4", description: "Would this be more iconic if done in another medium?"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 5", description: "What does the title mean?"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 6", description: "me lol"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 7", description: "Game of thrones reference"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 8", description: "I could've made that!"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 9", description: "what artists were inspired by this piece?"})
Comment.create({headline:"Comment 10", description: "proportions"})'''


Here's my schema: 

create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "headline"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "work_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "works", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "artist"
    t.text "year"
    t.string "medium"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end```
````

Comment: i think you should try in console (creating comment using that syntax) first then see if there is any errors

Comment: I suggest using `Comment.create!` (note the `!`) instead of `Comment.create`. When a `create` fails, for example, because of a failing validation then there is no error message and that error is simply ignored. Whereas `create!` will raise an exception with an error message that might help you debugging the problem.

Comment: yap it is true @spickermann . you should use bang (!) for see any error throw

Comment: @spickermann and @dedypuji thank you for the suggestion! I used the bang and got ```ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Work must exist, User must exist``` Does this mean theres something wrong with my relationships?

Comment: The validation error tells you that comments need to be associated with a user and a work. That means you need to create a work and a user first and you must pass both to new comments too.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann I'll try that!